# Trouble automating form login with Python Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I have been trying to automate a site login that requires cookies. I found an answer on this site, and replied to it, but I had problems logging in becasue I forgot I had an account here already. I apologize for the double post, but I was worried my reply wouldn't be seen.

[Can't automate login using python mechanize (must "activate" specific browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004322/cant-automate-login-using-python-mechanize-must-activate-specific-browser)

One question. When trying to replicate this, I run into an error.

```
File "test5.py", line 6, in <module>
self.br = mechanize.Browser( factory=mechanize.RobustFactory() )
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I usually script in Perl, but have been reading that this python module would be much easier for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import mechanize
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin

self.br = mechanize.Browser( factory=mechanize.RobustFactory() )
self.br.add_handler(PrettifyHandler())
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cj.save('cookies.txt', ignore_discard=False, ignore_expires=False)
self.br.set_cookiejar(cj)

self.br.addheaders = [('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                 ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'),
                 ('Referer', 'https://--------------/admin/login.jsp'),
                 ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'),
                 ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'),
                 ]
self.br.open('https://--------------/admin/login.jsp')

# Select the first (index zero) form
self.br.select_form(nr=0)
# User credentials
self.br.form['email'] = 'emailaddress'
self.br.form['password'] = 'password'
# Login
self.br.submit()
# Inventory
body = self.br.response().read().split('\n')
```

To me, it looks like a problem declaring the variable self, but i'm not too familiar enough with Python to know if that is the case.
Any ideas why I get this error would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE::
I was able to get past the initial error by remove all instances of self. Now when I run the following code, I get this error:

```
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
    mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'Loginform'
```

Below is the code:

```
!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import mechanize
import cookielib
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin, Browser
from time import sleep


class PrettifyHandler(mechanize.BaseHandler):
def http_response(self, request, response):
    if not hasattr(response, "seek"):
        response = mechanize.response_seek_wrapper(response)
    # only use BeautifulSoup if response is html
    if response.info().dict.has_key('content-type') and ('html' in     response.info().dict['content-type']):
        soup = MinimalSoup (response.get_data())
        response.set_data(soup.prettify())
    return response


br = mechanize.Browser( factory=mechanize.RobustFactory() )
br.add_handler(PrettifyHandler())
br.set_handle_robots(False)
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cj.save('cookies.txt', ignore_discard=False, ignore_expires=False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*  /*;q=0.8'),
                 ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'),
                 ('Referer', 'https://****/admin/login.jsp'),
                 ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'),
                 ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'),
                 ]
br.open('https://****/admin/login.jsp')

print br.response

 # Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(name='Loginform') 
#br.select_form(nr=0)
 # User credentials
br.form['email'] = 'luskbo@gmail.com'
br.form['password'] = 'password!!!'
 # Login
br.submit()
# Inventory
 body = br.response().read().split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove every `self.`, then it should work (if there arn't any other errors).

`self` usually is only used to refer to the current object from within a method in a class, not at module level.